# errors trying to transfer via SCP

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I'm trying to transfer a file between two servers and i'm getting different errors.

**Option 1: Logged at OLDSERVER via SSH**

> scp file.tar.gz root@IPADDRESS:/var/www/.

The error in this case is

> /usr/bin/ssh: no such file or directory

**Option 2: Logged at new server via SSH**

> scp OLDUSER@OLDURL:/var/htdocs/file.tar.gz /var/www/

The error in this case is

> ssh: connect to host OLDURL port 22: Connection refused

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: are you able to ssh to the host that you trying to scp?

Comment: it may seem stupid but is ssh installed on oldserver? or, is it installed in a standard place?

Answer (score 1):

#### Software Accessible?

On OLDSERVER and NEWSERVER confirm the location of `scp` and `ssh`. To do so run these commands:

```
$ type ssh
ssh is /usr/bin/ssh

$ type scp
scp is /usr/bin/scp
```

Make sure that this path is accessible to the user you're logging into on these respective systems as well. What can sometimes happen is `ssh` or `scp` may be in a non-standard location such as `/usr/local/bin`, and this directory may not be getting correctly added to this user's environment `$PATH` when you attempt to remotely `scp` files to it.

#### SSH Daemon running?

Confirm that `sshd` is running on both OLDSEVER & NEWSERVER.

```
$ pgrep -l sshd
```

For example:

```
$ pgrep -l sshd
1591 sshd
```

Comment: Also use `ps ax | grep ssh` to check that sshd is running on the target system.  It sounds as if OLDSERVER does not have the SSH daemon running.

Comment: @RobGibson - thanks, I've added your feedback to the answer!

Answer (score -1):

It turns out `OLDSERVER` was the wrong name; I had to replace it with `ssh.OLDSERVER`